# sIFR : Doesn't seem to work with nested HTML (e.g., <b> tag within an <h1> tag)

Tags: sifr

I have an H1 selector that I'm replacing with sIFR. Within some of the H1 selectors are < strong>< /strong> selectors; e.g.:

```
<h1>Hello world, <strong>this is some bold text</strong> and this is normal text</h1>
```

Everything outside of the < strong>< /strong> tags is replaced fine -- and the text within the  tags does not display. I'd like to apply different styling to the < strong> text. Is this possible?

Here is my relevant sIFR code from sifr-config.js:

```
sIFR.replace(avenir_black, {
  selector: 'h1',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #000000; text-transform:uppercase; }',
  wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

I tried adding this, but no luck:

```
sIFR.replace(avenir_black, {
  selector: 'h1 strong',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #cc0000; text-transform:uppercase; }',
  wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sIFR makes text inside `<strong>` tags bold. For the text to show up, the bold glyphs of the font need to have been exported. When creating the sIFR Flash movie, make sure to select a character and make it bold.

Comment: Mark,

Duh. That makes sense. The only problem is that the font I'm using (Avenir Black) doesn't have any bold glyphs. I'm assuming it's possible to select another wrapper with CSS, but I didn't have any luck.

For instance, I tried this:

<h1>This is some text <span>and this is bold</span></h1>

Then, in my sifr-config.js:

sIFR.replace(avenir_black, {
  selector: 'h1 span span',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color:red; }',
  wmode: 'transparent'
});

But that didn't work.

Comment: No, the `<span>` is already replaced as part of the `<h1>`. You can add `strong { font-weight: normal; }` to the CSS though to switch back to normal glyphs.